# Are there UI-related functions in Wordpress API?

Tags: php, api, wordpress

I have been working on various WP plug-ins for some time.

Each plug-in has its own admin pages, well integrated to the WP Admin menus thanks to the corresponding API functions (add_menu_page, add_submenu_page, ...).

I would like to go a little further into integration, by using the same widgets as those displayed in the real WP admin pages. So far, all I could find is the [WP_List_Table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) class, which is the widget used for most items lists in the WP admin (posts list, pages list, links lists...). Are there more classes and functions I could use to get a WP-like look-and-feel in my custom admin pages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has helped me a great deal in piggy-backing off the existing Wordpress style: [How To Design And Style Your WordPress Plugin Admin Panel](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/07/01/how-to-design-and-style-your-wordpress-plugin-admin-panel/)

Comment: And it's going to help me a great deal as well ! I wish google hinted me to it when I spent a couple hours looking for that kind of tutorials...Thanks for that link :)